# Join parent name only if parent exists

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join

I need to join parent names to child's row only if parent exists, otherwise do not join parent names to the row.

As the result I need to have row of childs with or without parent names.

How I can implement that?

```
SELECT t.*, cat.name AS cat_name
FROM products AS t
INNER JOIN category AS cat
ON category_id=cat.id
WHERE t.is_public!=2
```

Comment: Please add some sample table data, and expected result!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just replace your `INNER JOIN` with a [`LEFT JOIN`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Left_outer_join) and all products will be included in the result set, with `cat_name` being `NULL` for products without a parent/category.